# Sample an array with seed value to get consistent result

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am sampling several arrays and would like to add a seed value to get a consistent result every time its run, now and in the future.

My example:

```
constant_seed_value = 123456789
["a","b","c"].sample(seed: constant_seed_value ) should return "a" when run every time.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a `Random.new` with your seed to `sample`:

```
%w[a b c].sample(1, random: Random.new(123456789))
#=> ["a"]
```

See [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) and [Random](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Random.html)

Comment: Beat me to it. But I'll add some doc referrences to your answer.

Comment: I noticed that if I run `srand 1` before I run my `[].sample` it returns the same value all the time. Is this an ok way to do it too, so I do not need to pass the value each time?

Comment: _Is it an ok way_? Depends on what you actually try to achieve. You never told us why you want the random-based method `sample` not to return random values. Is it to test a method that otherwise would return random values?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the seed a constant (or write it to a file and read it each time the program is run). I assume you don't care what the seed actually is.

If a side-calculation produces

```
Random.new_seed
  #=> 44220669194288225494276674522501875094
```

you will write

```
SEED = 44220669194288225494276674522501875094
```

See [Random::new_seed](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Random.html#method-c-new_seed).

When the program is run you must initialize the seed to this value.

```
Random.srand(SEED)
  #=> 129123040985656142450143558000073927364
```

See [Random::srand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Random.html#method-c-srand).

Now let's compute some pseudo-random values.

```
arr = (1..1000).to_a
```

```
arr.sample(4)
  #=> [762, 619, 41, 997] 
rand
  #=> 0.9619996498741139 
rand
  #=> 0.7952214967836931
```

Now restore the initial seed, as we would do if we re-ran the program.

```
Random.srand(SEED)
  #=> 190782386885144604306184636344084340916
```

If we repeat the initial constuction of pseudo-random values we see they are the same as when we first computed them.

```
arr.to_a.sample(4)
  #=> [762, 619, 41, 997]
rand
  #=> 0.9619996498741139 
rand
  #=> 0.7952214967836931
```